# Yii2 language codes for Germany

Tags: php, yii2, translation

In Yii2 language translations are described in the [tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n). The locales are further stated in the [documentation of the ICU project](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale#TOC-The-Locale-Concept).

For German translations there are several definitions available.:

- `de-DE` for Germany
- `de-CH` for Switzerland
- `de-AT` for Austria

But there is additional complexity in each of these languages: there are two different translations for "you": "Sie" and "Du". In fact many text messages are different, e.g. "This is your message" translates to "Das ist Ihre Nachricht" and "Das ist Deine Nachricht".

In Web apps, both translations versions are used: Facebook translates to "Du", Amazon translates to "Sie".

How to handle these different language versions?

Do we need an additional German language "de-DU"? Are there best practices available?

**EDIT:**

I want both languages to be kept separately. When writing a module, the module has to work in "Du" and "Sie" environments. So this are two separate languages.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the problem here. Do you have own translations and want in one context translate `you` as `Sie`, and in the other context translate it as `Du`?

Comment: Please see my EDIT section.

Comment: You will have to roll your own convention then, something like "de-DE-formal".

Answer (score 1):

Both "Sie" and "Du" are part of the exact same locale.

They are not variants in the ICU sense, rather it's a question of whether you want to address your users in a formal or informal way.

You will face the issue in many other languages like Spanish or Japanese.

Comment: Please see the EDIT section in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating virtual languages is not a good choice, it will create confusion and problems with other translations. If you want to provide 2 versions of translations, you should rather use categories for this:

```
$mode = 'formal';
Yii::t('modules/MyModule/' . $mode, 'This is your message');
```

You can handle this at module level:

```
class MyModule extends \yii\base\Module {

    const TRANSLATION_MODE_FORMAL = 'formal';
    const TRANSLATION_MODE_UNFORMAL = 'unformal';

    public $translationMode = self::TRANSLATION_MODE_UNFORMAL;

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->registerTranslations();
    }

    public function registerTranslations() {
        Yii::$app->i18n->translations['modules/MyModule/*'] = [
            'class' => \yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource::class,
            'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
            'basePath' => __DIR__ . '/messages/' . $this->translationMode,
        ];
    }

    public static function t($category, $message, $params = [], $language = null) {
        return Yii::t('modules/MyModule/' . $category, $message, $params, $language);
    }
}
```

Configure mode at application configuration level:

```
'modules' => [
    'mymodule' => [
        'class' => MyModule::class,
        'translationMode' => 'formal',
    ],
],
```

And use module helper for translations:

```
MyModule::t('category', 'This is your message');
```